# When using a private git url for an npm module, how can I configure the consuming application to only use files from the module's dist folder?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli for my angular application, but because angular-cli currently does not support use for creating a library, I used the seemingly most widely used git project to create my library: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

My issue is that I don't want to publish my npm module library to the public directory. Instead I want to use the git url directly in my dependencies. During development, this works fine. I can run the build locally and run an npm link inside the "dist" folder and everything is dandy. However when I push my npm module code to git, and then run an npm install in the consuming project, I'm not sure how to set it so that my consuming project just looks inside the dist folder of the module and treats it as if it was the root of the module.

For example, in node_modules/my_private_module, my file structure looks like:

```
dist/
-- component1
-- compoennt2
-- my_module.metadata.json
-- my_module.d.ts
-- my_module.umd.js
-- index.d.ts
-- index.js
-- package.json
-- README.MD
package.json
README.md
```

All the files that my application is using are in the /dist folder, but I DO NOT want to specify "dist" in all my imports like

```
import { myComponent1 } from 'my_private_module/dist';
```

I want to be able to just specify

```
import { myComponent } from 'my_private_module";
```

As I do in development when I run an npm link in the dist folder.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In package.json for your module, in the root folder:

```
typings: 'dist/index.d.ts',
main: 'dist/index.js'
```

Remove the package.json in your dist folder.

When the package is resolved from `import {...} from 'my_private_module'`, the module loader will look for a folder called `my_private_module` under `node_modules`, and look either for `index.js` which defines the exports, or within package.json for the `main` property - which in your case also points to index.js from the dist folder.

It is good practice to put `package.json` where you want your module to be found, and have `main` and `typings` point to index.js and index.d.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942327/3772461) and it seems relevant.
Basically, treat the generated library in the dist folder as it's own repo. In order to keep the `git init` files and folders, you tell ng-packagr to not destroy the destination when building. Then you push the changes to the library specific repo and use that as your package url in other projects.