# Consume Angular library as git dependency

Tags: angular, npm

I have an Angular library hosted in a git repository but not published to npm. The library is packaged with ng-packagr. Is it possible to import it as a git dependency in another project?

Simply specifying the git URL as a npm dependency does not work, because ng-packagr builds the Angular library into the `dist` folder and that folder is usually published to npm. You can specify a `postinstall` script, but how can you configure afterwards that the root folder of the library is actually in the `dist` folder?

I don't want to publish to npm because the application is not open source. I could use a private npm repository, but I was thinking if I can avoid all the hassle.

Comment: I really don't understand the negative votes, I would say that it is a valid question and I explained what was already done and reasons.

Comment: Somebody with your reputation should already know that poorly asked questions gain negative votes. You have problems with particular library, yet you omitted this information. There is no magic solution for just random library. Were you satisfied with the answer that tries to address the problem in whole? The answers are as good as the question is. The problem may be solved by importing entry point from package `src` or somehow else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was actually to specify this as a git dependency, add a postinstall script and when importing I was importing `library/dist`.

Comment: Hey, im having the same issue, can you elaborate more on how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

In the `package.json` you can add git ssh as a dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
  "some-package": "github:github_username/some-package"
}
```

Then you can import the package from the component.

Comment: The problem is that ng-packagr builds the Angular5 package into the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is keeping the contents of the dist folder in it's own repo.
This is ONLY possible if you specify in the Library's package.json in ngPackage to NOT delete the destination path. You might also have to manually define the destination if you do this as well.

below is an example package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "ngPackage": {
    "dest": "../../dist/my-lib",
    "deleteDestPath": false
  }
}
```

you would then `git init` inside of my-lib and push it to it's own repo. That repo would become the dependency to other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. You can specify a git dependency in your `package.json` file like so and then use a `postinstall` script like this:

```
"scripts"
...
"postinstall": "npm i node_modules/some-package/dist/your-lib/your-lib-0.0.1.tgz"
},
"dependencies": {
  "some-package": "github:github_username/some-package",
...
}
```

Comment: How do you build the tgz and based on which part of the build ? It's not in the files done by build command.

Comment: the command to build the tgz is npm pack which you can run in the default Angular workspace :)

Comment: This is not good because it will change the reference the dependency to the disk version 
`file:node_modules/some-package/dist/your-lib/your-lib-0.0.1.tgz`
if the package and library have the same name

Comment: I suggest using `--no-save` in your post-install script to avoid adding a file dependency